# Scala vs. C++ for a distributed graph processing

Tags: c++, scala, graph

For parallel processing of graphs such as shortest path computation, would Scala outperform C++? If not, how much slower would it be (I'm assuming Scala concurrency is "easier" to write than C++ since C++ has no standard support for such things)

I'm considering learning Scala at the moment, both to learn a new language and because it seems to have good concurrency support. Once I'm done, I'm considering writing a distributed graph library to practice Scala, and for my own use, but if C++ is going to be faster and the benefits of easier to write code is not worth the tradeoff when performance is a concern, I'll have to rethink that quest.

Comment: "Languages do not have speed, implementations do." That being said, C++ runs significantly more "bare-metal" than Scala. Will this matter? It depends on the algorithm(s) / approach and what form of parallel processing (threaded/GPU/MPI/actors/etc.) and what libraries (and environments!) and where the bottlenecks materialize and developer proficiencies and ... etc ... Since you say "considering learning Scala" then **yes, by all means, do it**. The "worst" is you'll have learned some new approaches/concepts. Of course, perhaps to this end Haskell should be explored? ;-)

Comment: As far as "lack of" concurrent processing in C++, consider [Charm++](http://charm.cs.uiuc.edu/) oh ... you know ... parallel processing on 100k+ cores. (There are many parallel libraries/run-times from basic threaded to whatnot, even if "not part of the C++ specification/standard library").

Comment: There is the boost::graph library for C++ as well.

Comment: Yeah, I know about the Boost library's concurrency support, that's the library I had in mind when comparing C++ to Scala.

Thanks for the input, I'll start reading some Scala books once I'm done with my C++ books, and see if I can make that graph library.

Comment: there are also thrust and boost graphic library. there is also lua, which will interface really well. the learning curve is steeper so it's up to you how much time you want to invest.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'd suggest Scala over C++ for the following reasons:

- **Concurrency** - as you say, there is great concurrency support on the JVM and Scala is a good language to benefit from this. That is not to say that you can't write concurrent code in C++, but you will find it much easier "out of the box" in Scala.
- **Garbage collection** - a lot of graph algorithms benefit significantly from garbage collection vs. other memory management methods. Again, the garbage collection on the JVM is excellent (better than *anything* in the C++ world), and will make your algorithms much much easier to write.
- **Quality of JIT compiler** - For traversing object graphs in heap memory, I doubt there will be any noticeable performance difference between good C++ code and the code that the JVM JIT produces. The JVM is pretty heavily optimised for this kind of usage.

Of course, it is *possible* to write extremely performant code in C++. There are some situations where hand-tuned C/C++ code can outperform the JIT (e.g. by avoiding the need for array bounds checks or null pointer checks when you can prove that they aren't needed). Or you can write your own memory allocator that is specialised for graph processing and which theoretically might outperform the general purpose garbage collector in the JVM (though you better be a true genius if you want to try this....)

Overall though, it will be much more complex to write everything in C++ and the marginal performance improvement that you might theoretically be able to achieve is almost certainly not worth the effort.

Comment: Its not that hard to write c++ that out performs java is you specialize for a single architecture. That's what being so close to the metal means. Its just not worth the effort in general.

Comment: You may want to consider D as well (http://www.d-programming-language.org/). It compiles to native code like C/C++, has concurrency features and garbage collection.

Comment: boost and modern c++ approach takes care of all of these reasons. but scala is definitely more intuitive and requires less experience.

Answer (score 0):

Twitter just open sourced a Graph Processing library written in Scala.

https://github.com/twitter/cassovary

Comment: Haha how'd you find this question, so long ago. Yep I saw it, too bad it's not parallelized - I'm currently working on my own right now :)